# How to get the specific line from textfile containing a particular substring

Tags: c#, string, text-files

I have a textfile which contains texts.Now i have a string say `945789` .Now i want to get the line on which this string is present from the textfile but i am not able to search and get the line..
Here is the code.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
{
  //How to get the line with the string 
}
```

Please help me..

Update..

```
  for (int i = 9; i >=3; i--) {

  spsubcallingno = subcallingno.Substring(0, i);

   int lineNumber = 0;
   foreach (var spline in File.ReadAllLines(sp))
   {
   lineNumber++;
   if (line.Contains(spsubcallingno))
    {
   return lineNumber;
   }
   }
   }
```

I am getting a red line mark in return

Comment: Unless you keep an index you won't be able to know the line number if that's what you want. You can use a typical for loop and "i" is the line; right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183809/using-streamreader-to-check-if-a-file-contains-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `int` to count the lines:

```
public int GetLineNumber(string pathToFile, string content)
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
    {
         lineNumber++;
         if(line.Contains(content))
         {
             return lineNumber;
         }
    }
    return lineNumber;
}
```

Where `pathToFile` is the path to the text file and `content` is the text to look for on the line e.g. `945789`.

Comment: I have upadted my post ..Please see it ..I am getting error in return statetment

Comment: The return line assumes that this code is inside of a function that returns an int. If it's not, then you can change it to break; or use the updated answer provided.